# Push service shows up as inactive on the map console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed IBM Mobile First 8.0.0. I deployed Push service and the tables are also created. In the mobile first console the push service is showing as inactive. On inspecting the element in the chrome error window it points to GET URL returning 404.  When i paste the URL in the browser  and execute, it returns the live update adapter is not available and the database may be corrupted

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated

Comment: Try taking this question over to http://superuser.com/ if it's not a programming related issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the MobileFirst DevKit, then this shouldn't happen since everything is built-in. Try reinstalling in this case.

If this is a production or test environment installation using the IBM Installation Manager and Configuration tool, then you may have specified an incorrect path of the push services .war file. You can confirm this by comparing the various paths that are defined in the application server's server.xml file.